# How to identify and fix and external storage performance issues with macOS High Sierra

Tags: external-disk, high-sierra

I've just updated to High Sierra and immediately noticed that copying files from external storage devices is much slower than in previous versions.   While searching the web for info about what might be causing this, I noticed that every site is slow to load. So, I'm a little worried that something went awry with the clean install.

I suspect that the OS may be trying to index the external drive; however, I don't know how to verify this and regardless, it has never been this slow in previous upgrades. Another idea is that copying files from an older file system to the new file system requires some sort of translation.  Is that possible? Anyhow, it's torturing me right now. Project folders that used to take a few seconds to copy are now taking about 5 minutes.  What could cause this and can I fix it?

Oh, and I've been watching the Activity Monitor and nothing stands out.

Comment: Has this issue still been occurring? I'm not aware of any translation between HFS+ and APFS. macOS 10.13 is supposed to be completely compatible with any existing disks. I would use Disk Utility to run First Aid on your boot volume as well as your external disk and the volumes on it.

Comment: Actually, it got worse.  One of my external drives wasn't accessible at all, which of course threw me into a panic.  Fortunately, when I attached to a Windows machine there were no problems.  I doubt two external drives were going bad at the same time, but I haven't had the time or courage to try again, yet.  I just used Windows to move files to my NAS and from there to my Mac.